# Is TimeMachine Apple's System Restore?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, restore

I have recently moved to Mac from Windows. Rarely I find that I may have to use System Restore to fix an issue that the OS has incurred. What I would like to know is whether Time Machine is the Mac equivalent to this feature?

I do not need Time Machine file backups itself as I already make regular backups using rsync. But if Time Machine can also backup the OS will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, TimeMachine is Apple's way of doing backups (both user, and whole system, as long as you aren't excluding system files).

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1427